# C error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c

```
int i;
float h;

1/h=0;
for(i=1;1<=1000;++i)
{
    (1/h)+=(1/i);
    printf("%f",h);
}
```

So this is my code. I'm trying to find value of h according to this formula :

> (1/h)=(1/1)+(1/2)+(1/3)+....+(1/1000)

But i need to do it 1000 steps so that i can find h for

> (1/1)

and

> (1/1)+(1/2)

and

> (1/1)+(1/2)+(1/3)

and so on till

> (1/1)+(1/2)+(1/3)+...+(1/1000)

I think my loop here is correct but the thing is i get this error saying

> [Error] lvalue required as left operand of assignment

for lines `1/h=0` and `(1/h)+=(1/i)`
So what's my mistake and its solution? Thanks.

Comment: You need to solve for `h`, what got you thinking that `1/h += 1/i` make sense?

Comment: You need to use a bit of algebra

Comment: how about I write `10+=5;`. Do you get the idea? :)

Comment: Do you think `n*n = 9;` sets n to 3?

Comment: @SouravGhosh That would be `15`, or `105`? I am confused now. No, just kidding.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the `1 <= 1000` before. ... WoW! What does it mean? It's certainly always true.

Comment: @iharob I didn't notice that neither. It should be i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1/h = 0` and `(1/h) += (1/i)` don't work because you're trying to assign a value the result of an *expression*, not an object.  It's like writing `1 = 2` and expecting it to be meaningful; it isn't.

You're trying to solve for `h`.  So you need to sum `1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ...` and take the inverse:

```
double u = 0.0; // u == 1/h == 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ...

for ( int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++ )
{
  u += 1.0 / i;
}
printf( "1/h = %f, h = %f\n", u, 1.0/u );
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `1/h` is an expression not an *lvalue*, you can't assign to expressions. You can read about what constitutes an *lvalue* in the [c](/questions/tagged/c) standard.

Try this

```
int i;
double h;
double u;

u = 0;
for (i = 1 ; i <= 1000 ; ++i)
    u += 1.0 / (double) i;
h = 1.0 / u;

fprintf(stdout, "1/h = %f\n", h);
```

Is the value correct?

Comment: It outputs 1/h=0.133592 but i need h. I'm using 32 bit btw(not sure if double will give correct result for me but i'm a noob so...)

Comment: It has nothing to do with 32 or 64 bits. Double precision has more precision, and since you are adding very tiny values together I recommend `double`.

Comment: @EdHeal Of course we did. Don't go hard on me please. My question is not about algebra, it's about getting the right output therefore it's about the code that i need to use.

Comment: @SamedYalçın - The question is all to do with algebra.

Comment: @EdHeal Let's not argue about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int i ;
double h , a ;


a = 0 ;

for( i = 1 ; i <= 1000 ; ++i )
{
    a += 1.0 / (double) i;

    h = 1 / a ;

    printf("%lf",h);

}
```

I changed my code to this. I get the result I want I guess. I'm not sure because I didn't calculate the values for each step. But in every step the value is decreasing so it should be right.

I'm still not sure if that's the perfect or right way to express myself. It will be appreciated if you can give comments about my code.

Comment: the `l` is ignored in `printf("%lf", h);`.  The correct way to print a `double` (or a `float`) is `printf("%f", h);`

Comment: @chqrlie Our "professor" said that `%lf` specifier is used for `double` and `%f` for `float`. That's not right appearently.

Comment: that's true for `scanf`, but not for `printf`:  `float` values are converted to `double` as they are passed to `printf` and the format for this type is either `%e`, `%f` or `%g` and their uppercase counterparts. Thankfully, the `l` is ignored by `printf`, so it is harmless, but not strictly correct.